# Remove Python alias to use virtualenv for Python

Tags: linux, bash, python, virtualenv

When I install `virtualenv` and activate it `which python` returns my `/usr/bin/python`. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003859/python-still-runs-the-system-version-after-virtualenv-activate) it is because I have python alias in my bash startup scipt and virtualenv doesn't work with it.

However, I can't find word `python` neither in `.profile` or `.bashrc` file in Kubuntu 17.10. What should I do to make virtualenv use virtual environment and where to find and delete those aliases?

Comment: What does `type -a python` show?

Comment: In my `project_env` it returns `python is /usr/bin/python` and also when I deactivate it.

Comment: first thing - improve your shebang -  #!/usr/bin/env/python

Comment: You mean `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: After you've activated the virtual env, what does your `PATH` look like? Also, what is `path/to/project_env/bin/python -V`?